# Slurm do not limit number of available GPUs in job when --gres is not set

Tags: python, gpu, nvidia, slurm

I have a all-in-one node with 4 GPUs. I meet the problem that **all GPUs** are available for job if the **--gres=gpu:n** is not set.

The env "$CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES" is null. This is expected.

This is my srun command:

```
srun --mpi=none -n1 -p debug python test_gpu.py
```

```
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    # Get the number of available GPUs
    num_gpus = torch.cuda.device_count()
```

the num_gpus is **4**. and all GPUs are available.

This is my **slurm.conf**:

```
SlurmctldHost=gpu-server35
GresTypes=gpu
MpiDefault=none
ProctrackType=proctrack/cgroup
ReturnToService=1
SlurmctldPidFile=/var/run/slurmctld.pid
SlurmctldPort=6817
SlurmdPidFile=/var/run/slurmd.pid
SlurmdPort=6818
SlurmdSpoolDir=/var/spool/slurmd
#SlurmUser=slurm
SlurmdUser=root
#SrunEpilog=
#SrunProlog=
StateSaveLocation=/var/spool
SwitchType=switch/none
#TaskEpilog=
TaskPlugin=task/cgroup,task/affinity

#
# SCHEDULING
#DefMemPerCPU=0
#MaxMemPerCPU=0
#SchedulerTimeSlice=30
SchedulerType=sched/backfill
SelectType=select/cons_tres
SelectTypeParameters=CR_Core
#

#
# LOGGING AND ACCOUNTING
AccountingStorageType=accounting_storage/none
#AccountingStorageUser=
AccountingStoreJobComment=YES
ClusterName=cluster
JobCompType=jobcomp/none
#JobCompUser=
#JobContainerType=job_container/none
JobAcctGatherFrequency=30
#JobAcctGatherType=jobacct_gather/none
JobAcctGatherType=jobacct_gather/cgroup #optional for gathering metrics
PrologFlags=Contain                     #X11 flag is also suggested
SlurmctldDebug=info
SlurmctldLogFile=/var/log/slurmctld.log
SlurmdDebug=info
SlurmdLogFile=/var/log/slurmd.log

# COMPUTE NODES
NodeName=gpu-server35 Gres=gpu:tesla:2 CPUs=48 RealMemory=200000 Sockets=2 CoresPerSocket=12 ThreadsPerCore=2 State=UNKNOWN
PartitionName=debug Nodes=gpu-server35 Default=YES MaxTime=INFINITE State=UP
```

**cgroup.conf**

```
CgroupAutomount=yes
CgroupMountpoint=/sys/fs/cgroup
ConstrainCores=yes
ConstrainDevices=yes
ConstrainKmemSpace=no        #avoid known Kernel issues
ConstrainRAMSpace=yes
ConstrainSwapSpace=yes
TaskAffinity=no              #use task/affinity plugin instead
```

Slurm limit number of available GPUs in job

Comment: What do you have in `gres.conf`?

Comment: @damienfrancois thx, I add gres.conf that solve the problem if I set -gres=gpu:1 and all GPUs are available. But I have another problem:
if the --gres=gpu:n is not set, all GPUs are available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing is to make sure the `gres.conf` file is complete, with the `File=` parameter properly specified.

Then, if the `cgroup` configuration is correct, only the GPUs allocated by Slurm should be visible to the job processes. Running `nvidia-smi` in a GPU-less job on a HPU node should return

```
No devices were found
```

If that is no the case, you should double check the cgroup configuration (which appears correct in your case) and make sure all daemons have loaded that configuration (restart them all to be sure).

You can also set `export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=` in the [Slurm task prolog](https://slurm.schedmd.com/prolog_epilog.html) but beware that this can be overridden by the job program.

Comment: With the File= parameter properly specified, it woks.  Thx.